# drop down population based on locale (sightly AEM)

Tags: sightly

I am new to AEM, consider my js would return itemList (for ex: var itemList = list.getItems();).
The skeleton of each Item would be:

```
interface Item {

            /**
                 * Get the item's title.
                 * 
                 * @return the title
                 */
                @Nonnull
                String getTitle();

                /**
                 * Get the item's localized title.
                 * 
                 * @param locale the locale for localization
                 * 
                 * @return the title
                 */
                @Nonnull
                String getTitle(Locale locale);

                /**
                 * Get the item's value.
                 * 
                 * @return the value
                 */
                @Nonnull
                String getValue();
            }
```

How can I get the locale based title (i.e calling `getTitle(locale)`) in place of `${list.title}` mentioned in the below HTML code of `select` tag (I need both title(locale) and value in the itemlist):
 option value="${list.value}">${list.title}

Answer (score 0):

From Sightly, you cannot access methods with parameters.

However, in the Use-API, the same global variables are available as in the Sightly execution context, and you can also pass parameters to the initialization of the Use-API.

In Java code, you can for instance access the page language with something like that:

```
PageManager pageManager = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(PageManager.class);
Page currentPage = pageManager.getContainingPage(request.getResource());
Locale locale = currentPage.getLanguage(false);
```

Else, to pass parameters to the Java Use-API, this is how it goes:

```
<div data-sly-use.foo="${'Foo' @ locale='es'}">
    <h1>${foo.titleLocalized}</h1>
</div>
```

And the corresponding Java:

```
public class Foo extends WCMUsePojo {
    private String locale;

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        String locale = get("locale", String.class);
    }

    public String titleLocalized() {
        ...
    }
}
```